how to create a foreground Service with notification in api34
hey guys i have a problem in api34 when i create a foreground service it crashes when i start it , even thoght for api33 it works just fine .
this service is responsible of showing a notification when it is started and getting the location but i comment it and the problem isn't because of the location
Serrvice class
package com.example.locateme.model;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat;

import com.example.locateme.R;
import com.example.locateme.view.MainActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.CurrentLocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Granularity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Priority;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationTokenSource;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;


public class SendSmsAndLocation extends Service {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("tag","service working");

        createNotificationChannel();

        Notification notification=getNotification();
        ServiceCompat.startForeground(this,10,notification,ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
        //startForeground(1, notification);
        fusedLocationProviderClient= 
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
        getLocation();
      

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("tag","service stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLocation() {
        CurrentLocationRequest currentLocationRequest= new CurrentLocationRequest.Builder()
                .setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_FINE)
                .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setDurationMillis(5000)
                .setMaxUpdateAgeMillis(2000).
                build();
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource=new CancellationTokenSource();
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation(currentLocationRequest,
                cancellationTokenSource.getToken()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Location location=task.getResult();
                    Log.v("tag","location is "+location);
                }else{
                   Log.v("tag","problem");

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("+213"+phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Notification getNotification() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setOngoing(true)  //persistent notification!
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle("Service")   //Title message top row.
                .setContentText("Service is running")  //message when looking at the notification, second row
                .build();  //finally build and return a Notification.
    }


    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription("Channel for Foreground Service");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

}


Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocateMe"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".model.SendSmsAndLocation"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location|remoteMessaging"
            android:exported="false"
             />

        <receiver android:name=".model.SMSReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>

Build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
   }

android {
    namespace = "com.example.locateme"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.locateme"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding=true
    }

}

dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    val lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    //DrawerLayout
    implementation ("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0")
    //CardView
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    //RecyclerView
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")

    implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2")
    implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")

    //Location google play services
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")
    //androidx core for android 14
    
    // Java language implementation
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.12.0")

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

}

i started the service in api33 and it shows a notification very normal
but for api34 it just craches when i start the service

well what is the error when it crashes

When it crashes it doesn't show any error msg it just closes the app

there is always an error you need to check android studio

Can you tell me how to check for errors cause i usually check them in the build output section and for this nothing shows

I found this exception

FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.example.locateme, PID: 8503java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.locateme.model.SendSmsAndLocation@4f0003e with Intent { cmp=com.example.locateme/.model.SendSmsAndLocation }: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type location callerApp=ProcessRecord{221bee2 8503:com.example.locateme/u0a191} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions

allOf=false [android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

you know what i deleted some unused importation in the phoneNumber class in the room database and now it is working hhhh
